# jQuery cycle plugin help

Tags: jquery, cycle

Can someone help me do one of two things.

1) Make the cycle plugin highlight the relevant button.

- or -

2) Make the cycle plugin stop rotating once a button is clicked.

My problem is that the images cycle, then I click a button. The cycling resumes but the previously selected button stays highlighted. Either fix will be suitable. Perhaps fix 1 is preferable but I am easy really.

Here is what I have at the moment.

```
var $container = $('#slider .inner').cycle({ 
 fx:     'scrollHorz', 
 speed: 300,
 timeout: 4000 
}); 

$container.children().each(function(i) { 
 // There are only 3 images, this is to stop a random 4th button being created.
 if (i != 3) {
  $('<input type="button" value="'+(i+1)+'" />') 
   // append it to button container 
   .appendTo(bc) 
   // bind click handler 
   .click(function() { 
    // cycle to the corresponding slide 
    $container.cycle(i);

    $(".home_buttons input").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false; 
   });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use cycles pager function will build the list for you and add 'activeSlide' as a class to that item: pager just add:

```
pager: '#nav'
```

(or whatever container you want the list built in) to your options within cycle. Demo here: x http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html though it sounds like you won't nessecarily need the page anchor bit

Comment: it does work very well and it solved a lot of my cycle needs. The only problem I have is to customize the nav buttons, it writes `<a>` and if you want to add an extra class or a span or whatever there's no way (that I know of).

Comment: You could just target the list in your css?

     #nav a {...}

Or if you need an individual class or id for each could iterate through the list

    $('#nav a').each(function(i){

      $(this).addClass('item'+i);

});

then you'll end up with <a class="item1"> ... <a class="item2" and so on.